# Updating graphic drivers issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I have some issue. I installed ubuntu via EFI. Now when I want to install latest drivers for my graphic card i have messege "this device uses a manually installed driver" and I don't know how to change it. Have anyone answer? :D

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem doing those steps:

sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'

sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install

Reboot

sudo apt-get remove libnvidia-gl-530 libnvidia-compute-530 libnvidia-extra-530 nvidia-compute-utils-530 libnvidia-decode-530 libnvidia-encode-530 nvidia-utils-530 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-530 libnvidia-cfg1-530 libnvidia-fbc1-530

Reboot

sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude install nvidia-driver-530

disconnect external monitors, reboot and then connect them again.

Answer (score -1):

OK. I have solution!
You need to add repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

and next use command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

After reboot system will have newest driver :D